# How Spring HttpMessageConverter parse request body to the model that I define

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am a bit curious how spring handle this, and I did some experiment.
Here is my request handling method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/testRequestBody")
public String testRequestBody(@RequestBody MyRequestBody requestBody) {
    System.out.println(requestBody);

    return "Success";
}
```

I have tried three types of `MyRequestBody`.

Tyep 1:

```
public class MyRequestBody {
private int id;
private String name;
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String toString() {
    return "MyRequestBody(id="+id+",name="+name+")";
}}
```

Type 2:

```
public class MyRequestBody {
private int id;
private String name;
public MyRequestBody(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
public String toString() {
    return "MyRequestBody(id="+id+",name="+name+")";
}}
```

Type 3:

```
public class MyRequestBody {
private int id;
private String name;
public String toString() {
    return "MyRequestBody(id="+id+",name="+name+")";
}}
```

Both Type 1 and Type 2 I can get `MyRequestBody(id=1,name=test name)` in the console, for input `{"id": 1,"name": "test name"}`, and Type 3 gives me `MyRequestBody(id=0,name=null)`. It seems Spring is able to choose different way to parse my model based on how setters and constructors are defined for my model. I would like to know how does Spring achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java) delegates to Jackson, the work of converting json to a java object. So, the behaviour that you are seeing can be explained by the rules jackson follows.

Following is a simplified sequence of the operations that Jackson performs, which explains the behavior that you are seeing with the three `MyRequestBody` definitions.

- An object of the class is created by invoking the constructor. If the constructor accepts parameters, the values for the parameters are taken from the json string. Following are the rules to decide which constructor should be invoked.

  - If there is a constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator`, that constructor is invoked.
  - If there is no constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator`

    - If there is exactly one constructor, that constructor is invoked. This could be either a parameterized constructor or a default constructor.
    - If there are multiple constructors, including a default constructor, the default constructor is invoked.
    - In other cases, an exception is thrown.
- Field values are set by calling setX() methods.

[Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is used for examining the constructor/methods and invoking them.

So, in your case

- For the first RequestBody definition, default constructor is invoked and setX() methods are called.
- For the second RequestBody definition, parameterized constructor is invoked (there is no default constructor)
- The default constructor is invoked.